# Spring JPA + JDBC in same transaction

Tags: spring, jpa, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-jdbc

If a transaction is started using Spring's @Transactional, is there any issue using a combination of JPA and JDBC within this transaction?

Meaning, will the transactional handling still work as expected where if an rollback happens, it will rollback all JPA and JDBC changes?

The JPA access would be done through Spring Data repositories and the JDBC access through JdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no issue.
As both JPA and JDBC simply execute SQL in the same transaction.

Comment: Apart from the normal JPA issue of caching.

Comment: @JensSchauder He was asking about rollback and transactional behavior, which is not affected by any caching. Or which issue were you thinking of?

Comment: Things like "save" something with JPA and not being able to read it with JDBC although they use the same transaction/connection because JPA delays writes.

Comment: @JensSchauder That's for sure an issue.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was mostly making sure the normal atomic nature of a transaction would apply. After posting this I did find some other posts about the save/read issue you mentioned and needing to call flush(). Thanks!